# Run script after vue development server starts

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vite

I have a script called `modifyFile.js` that I would like to run right after the vue development server starts. Currently, I have the `dev` script as `"vite && npm run modifyFile"` However, the `modifyFile` script never runs since vite spins up a server and the server is still running.

How do I go about fixing it? I want to run both actions in one command - `npm run dev`.

```js
// package.json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite && npm run modifyFile",
    "modifyFile": "node modifyFile.js",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 4173",
  },

}
```

Comment: Did you try to use post hook ? In scripts: `"dev": "vite"` after that add script named `"postdev": "npm run modifyFile"`

Comment: @Batuhan - what makes you think such a "hook" exists?

Comment: @JaromandaX you can check the docs at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts. You just have to add "post" pr "pre" with a matching name

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw - thank you, I've learned something today :p

Comment: No problem. I was in a similar situation weeks ago 

Comment: @Donut Did you find any solution ? I can add an answer to the question.

Comment: @Batuhan I tried the post hook and it doesn't work. It has the same issue as what I have now. `npm run dev` never ends so `npm run postdev` never runs.

Comment: @Donut I see the vite runs as server. It seems you need to use vite hooks. Here is the what i mean https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#universal-hooks